# Slow WordPress default query

Tags: mysql, wordpress, performance

My WordPress admin gone very slow. I approached the hosting provider and diagnosed by a slow query which is below taking typically a minute to run.

```
SELECT
    wp_posts.ID
FROM
    wp_posts
WHERE
    1 = 1
AND (
    (
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT
                1
            FROM
                wp_term_relationships
            INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
            WHERE
                wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'rl_media_folder'
            AND wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID
        )
    )
)
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'attachment'
AND (
    (
        wp_posts.post_status = 'inherit'
        OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private'
    )
)
GROUP BY
    wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY
    wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Can anyone help why this is causing slow admin and any possible solution for it?

Comment: What is the size of ```wp_term_relationships```? I believe that subquery slow things down.

Answer (score 0):

I believe (*without adequate proof*) that moving the `EXISTS` clause to the end of the `WHERE` clause would improve speed.

Also, using InnoDB would probably be faster than MyISAM.